# Django - ckeditor is not working - customization

Tags: django, ckeditor

I am trying to customize my ckeditor in Django setting like this. But I am getting 500 error once I save the setting. Otherwise the ckeditor is working but if I am trying to customize it, it fails.

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
```

Can someone help me please, how to make my own "config" without rewriting the basic one, please ?

Comment: Could you provide some more information, like the snippet of code where  you implement your CKEditor, what Django version you are using etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your prJ at settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'ckeditor',]
```

and

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'width': '500px',
        'height': '10%',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'],

        ],
    }
}


CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
```